# How to rename everything matching a certain string in a folder

Tags: linux, command-line, rename, recursive

I want/need to rename **everything** within a folder that matches a given string. By everything I mean:

- folders/files
- content within a file
- content in hidden files

Basically, I want to refactor a Java-project. Sure, I could use Eclipse to handle the replacing, but this leaves out the folders or resources outside of my workspace.

I was thinking of a script that could do the job for me but this seems rather tricky. For instance when it comes to folder-/file-rename I want to replace only the part of the name that matches my string, the rest should remain untouched.

Maybe someone already has something like this in his/her script-collection?

Comment: woops...I just realized this better goes to SUPERUSER. Can someone move this question please. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty way of doing this could be:

1. Get a list of all files that match your pattern

   ```
   # find /path -name \*pattern\* > filelist
   ```
2. Iterate through filelist with a shell script, doing whatever you want to each line:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   for I in `cat filelist`
   do
        # for renaming, use mv
        mv $I new.file.name
   done
   ```

Comment: This does not rename the content within the files. Also, if there are any spaces in the file names, the `\`cat filelist\`` will break.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to do this in several steps

1. Generate list of files containing the string you want to change (e.g., `find mydir -type f -print | xargs egrep <searchstring>`)
2. For each of those files, do the substitutions (e.g., `| while read fn; do sed 's/searchstring/replacement/g' $fn >/tmp/foo && mv /tmp/foo $fn; done`)
3. Now find directory names to change (e.g., `find mydir -type d -print | egrep <searchstring>`)
4. and change them (e.g., `| while read olddir; do newdir=echo $olddir | sed 's/searchstring/replacement/g'; mv $olddir $newdir; done`) (there should be backtics around the echo | sed newdir assignment; I'd appreciate a comment on how to include backtics in an inline code segment)
5. And now filenames, since the directory names won't change.  Very similar to the directory change, only the initial `find` should be `-type f`

That should be enough to get you going.

Comment: To include the backticks, escape them with  `\\``

Comment: This is closer to correct if not correct btw. +1

Comment: @drewk: tried that (and repeated after your comment) -- works for inserting backtick in normal text, but loses the <code> insert

Comment: I couldnt get your example with the filenames to work. It looks like he is complaining about whitespaces, so I tried the -print0 option but it didnt help.

But it looks like the content of the files has been replaced in some cases

Answer (score 0):

For example, if the file name is "FILE_SAMPLE" and I want to change it to "FILE_TOTO", the script would be:

```
find . -type f -name 'FILE_*' | while read FILE ; do
    newfile="$(echo ${FILE} |sed -e 's/\SAMPLE/TOTO/')" ;
    mv "${FILE}" "${newfile}" ;
done
```